# How do I override init - message without creating unwanted recursion in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to subclass `UIBarButtonItem` with an initializer that automatically sets the image, target and selector.

I tried to override the `- (id) init` message like this:

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(myMessage)];
    if (self) {
        //Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

This results in an unwanted recursion, because `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action` calls `init`.

I read the answer to the following question, but it didn't help me as it still gives me the same recursion:
[Custom init method in Objective-C, how to avoid recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888970/custom-init-method-in-objective-c-how-to-avoid-recursion)

The code I used when testing this was the following:

```
- (id)initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItem)systemItem target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
        return [super initWithBarButtonSystemItem:systemItem target:target action:action];
}

- (id) init {
    self = [self initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(myMessage)];
    if (self) {
        //Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have the same requirements as the author of the mentioned question:

- I don't want to create a custom init like `- (id) initCustom`.
- I don't want to use a flag to determine if the `init` has already been run once.

I also want to mention that I tried to create the `UIBarButtonItem` without using the `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action` initializer - but I couldn't find a `@property` corresponding to the first parameter.

Thank you!

Comment: I know you said you didn't want an `initCustom` method but that is the proper solution.

Comment: I know this is an Obj-C question, but I would recommend reading the Swift guide's section on [Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_323). Swift formalizes the notion of "designated" and "convenience" initializers, in order to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: @rmaddy, thats disappointing..

Comment: @jtbandes, I will have a look at that!

Comment: @user1401083 Why? You have a special `init` that you wish to implement. Giving it a special name makes sense. The default `init` has a certain meaning. You want another `init` with another meaning so give it a name that indicates that meaning.

Comment: @rmaddy Because I have created a custom class, that with its name describes the difference from its parent class. I don't want to describe that difference also in the `init` message.
I want to create an `init` message, just like the `init` message of any other class.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link you have provided (see the accepted answer), if you initialise with `super` call, it will not result in recursive calls.

Probably you should have something like this:

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(myMessage)];
    if (self) {
        //Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, that didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I see the difference now, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful: [Concepts in Objective-C: Object Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html)

In particular, pay attention to the concept of the designated initializer:

> The designated initializer plays an important role for a class. It ensures that inherited instance variables are initialized by invoking the designated initializer of the superclass. It is typically the init... method that has the most parameters and that does most of the initialization work, and it is the initializer that secondary initializers of the class invoke with messages to self.
>
> When you define a subclass, you must be able to identify the designated initializer of the superclass and invoke it in your subclass’s designated initializer through a message to super. You must also make sure that inherited initializers are covered in some way. And you may provide as many convenience initializers as you deem necessary. When designing the initializers of your class, keep in mind that designated initializers are chained to each other through messages to super; whereas other initializers are chained to the designated initializer of their class through messages to self.

This is why you are seeing this behavior. `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action` is the designated initializer for that class, and it in turn calls `init`. Overriding `init` to call a designated initializer won't for the very reasons you are describing.

Instead, you can create a convenience constructor that calls the designated initializer:

```
+ (instancetype) bookmarksBarButtonItemWithAction:(SEL)action {
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:action];
}
```

Which would achieve pretty much what you are looking for, and does not even require that you subclass `UIBarButtonItem`. It can be done as a category.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It didn't answer my question though. It made me even more confused since they present an example doing the same thing I'm trying to do. The kind of initializer I'm trying to create is called a _convenience initializer_ and should be able to take the name `init`. Look at the example with the `Task` class. Do I miss anything?

Comment: >"This is why you are seeing this behavior. initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action is the designated initializer for that class, and it in turn calls init. Overriding init to call a designated initializer won't for the very reasons you are describing."